# Can i avoid to print new line between 2 for loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, newline, shapes

I'm trying to display a diamond shape depending on the input. Code almost worked done except 'empty new line'.

But I didn't eliminate the empty line between 2 loops. How can I fix it? Is there something that escaped my attention?

```
def print_shape(n):

    for i in range(0,n):
        print('*' * (n-i), end='')
        print(' ' * (i*2), end='')
        print('*' * (n-i), end='\n')
    for k in range((n), (2 * n + 1)):
        print('*' * (k - n), end='')
        print(' ' * ((4 * n) - (2 * k)), end='')
        print('*' * (k - n), end='\n')

n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print_shape(n)
```

```
Enter a number: 5

**********
****  ****
***    ***
**      **
*        *
          
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
```

```
Need to do this one:

**********
****  ****
***    ***
**      **
*        *
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
```

Comment: Just change `range(0,n)` to `range(0,n-1)`

Comment: @mousetail that doesn't work

Comment: @AlexandreNovius no you don't, only need to change the 2nd one

Comment: Think what happens for k == n in the second loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's very easy. Just start from `n+1` instead of `n` in the bottom loop (it's the one printing the unwanted newline) like so

```
def print_shape(n):

    for i in range(0,n):
        print('*' * (n-i), end='')
        print(' ' * (i*2), end='')
        print('*' * (n-i), end='\n')
    for k in range(n + 1, (2 * n + 1)):  # <--- here
        print('*' * (k - n), end='')
        print(' ' * ((4 * n) - (2 * k)), end='')
        print('*' * (k - n), end='\n')

n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print_shape(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
def print_shape(n):

  for i in range(0,n):
    print('*' * (n-i), end='')
    print(' ' * (i*2), end='')
    if i == n-1:
      print('*' * (n-i), end='')
    else:
      print('*' * (n-i), end='\n')
  for k in range((n), (2 * n + 1)):
    print('*' * (k - n), end='')
    print(' ' * ((4 * n) - (2 * k)), end='')
    print('*' * (k - n), end='\n')
      
print_shape(5)
```